# Creating data frame without duplicates in one column but could have duplicates in others

Tags: r

I have a problem creating a matrix when my data frame contains duplicates on both columns
Example

```
n = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B')
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc","dd","aa","cc")
df = data.frame(n, s)
```

But using df I need to create something like this:
new data frame (NDF)

```
A  "aa" "dd"
B  "bb" "aa" "cc"
C  "cc"
```

As you can see,  I used only unique values from column n on my data frame df and the rows are filled with values from df$s, the latest value in this example could be zero or na (right now is empty).

```
F<-matrix(nrow=length(unique(df$n)),ncol=length(unique(df$s)))
```

But when I tried to make a loop here (For (i)...For.(j)...) I could not figure it out how to do it./
Any help is more than welcome
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your question!

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you want since a `data.frame` has to be rectangular.

Maybe you want this:

```
tapply(s, n, list)
#$A
#[1] "aa" "dd"
#
#$B
#[1] "bb" "aa" "cc"
#
#$C
#[1] "cc"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dcast` function from `plyr` package to get the following data.frame:

```
dcast(data=df, n ~ s)
  n   aa   bb   cc   dd
1 A   aa <NA> <NA>   dd
2 B   aa   bb   cc <NA>
3 C <NA> <NA>   cc <NA>
```

If you want to have all non-NA values "in front" you need to do more. I've come to the following solution, which isn't pretty at all but works.

```
x <- dcast(data=df, n ~ s)
t(apply(x ,1 ,function(x){
                          tmp <- sum(is.na(x))
                          c(x[complete.cases(x)], rep(NA,tmp))
                          }))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "A"  "aa" "dd" NA   NA  
[2,] "B"  "aa" "bb" "cc" NA  
[3,] "C"  "cc" NA   NA   NA
```